# Tokio macro requires rt or rt-multi-thread in Solana program

Tags: rust, solana, rust-tokio, solana-program-library

Anyone able to guide me on why I can be getting this error on my tests?

`The #[tokio::test] macro requires rt or rt-multi-thread.`

It is more a Rust question than a Solana one, but I have been following the examples (and I am learning Rust), so just felt here would be a good place to post hte quesiton.

I have `solana-program-test = "1.6.2"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hrm... I'm not sure then. Maybe try adding https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/364af3a3e01e258694e16aed57838d36305aa9c3/program-test/Cargo.toml#L25 explicitly?

Under `dev-dependencies` though.

Answer (score 0):

You cargo.toml should have `tokio` and `tokio-test`

```rust
tokio = { version = "1.24.2", features = ["full"] }
tokio-test ="0.4.2"
```

This will install the optional `rt-multi-thread` dependency.